# Prove this inequality $\sum\limits_\text{cyc}\sqrt{1-xy}\ge 2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Let $x,y,z\ge 0$, and $x+y+z=2$, show that
$$\sqrt{1-xy}+\sqrt{1-yz}+\sqrt{1-xz}\ge 2.$$

Mt try: $$\Longleftrightarrow 3-(xy+yz+zx)+2\sum_\text{cyc}\sqrt{(1-xy)(1-yz)}\ge 4$$
or
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\sqrt{(1-xy)(1-yz)}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}(1+xy+yz+zx)$$

Comment: What does $cyc$ denote?

Comment: @AlexisOlson it would mean that the sum is taken over all cyclic permutations of x,y,z (so there are 3 terms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After squaring of the both sides we need to prove that
$$2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(1-xy)(1-xz)}\geq1+xy+xz+yz$$ or
$$2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{((x+y+z)^2-4xy)((x+y+z)^2-4xz)}\geq(x+y+z)^2+4(xy+xz+yz)$$ or
$$2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{((x-y)^2+z^2+2xz+2yz)((x-z)^2+y^2+2xy+2yz)}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+6xy)$$
and after using C-S it remains to prove that
$$2\sum_{cyc}((x-y)(x-z)+xy+2x\sqrt{yz}+2xy)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+6xy)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2-2xy+4x\sqrt{yz})\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^2-\sqrt{x^3y}-\sqrt{x^3z}+x\sqrt{yz}\right)+\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{x^3y}+\sqrt{x^3z}-2xy\right)+3\sum_{cyc}x\sqrt{yz}\geq0$$
which is Schur and Muirhead.

Comment: It's very nice!Thank you+1

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg-how did you come up with that solution, what were your thought process?

Answer (score 1):

Lets minimise the LHS.  WLOG let $x \ge y \ge z \ge 0$ - i.e. $x \in [y, 2], y \in [z, x], z \in [0, y]$.

The LHS is concave in all variables, hence its minima will happen when $x, y, z $ take extreme values in their allowable intervals.  Along with the constraint, this leads to only three possibilities viz. $(x, y, z) \in \{(2, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (\frac23, \frac23, \frac23)\}$

In particular note that the minimum is given when $x=y=1, z=0$ (or permutations of it).

Comment: This problem is contest ,so maybe have other methods

Comment: @Macavity your solution is total wrong! There is a condition, otherwise we can check $(0,0,0)$, which does not work.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The condition / constraint is of course being used when finding the three possibilities.

Comment: If so you can not use convexity because a variables depend of each other.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Think of it as unconstrained at first, then a closed convex compact domain imposed.  The minimum has to be at the corners of the domain now by concavity of the objective function.  Similar logic to your $u, v, w$ approach really.

Comment: You can not say about convexity if you have a condition. OK. Why LS is a concave  of $x$? Explain please.

Comment: By the way, the uvw's reasoning we use always after  condition killing.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748739/min-of-concave-symmetric-function-on-a-convex-set?rq=1 for an illustration.  Couldn't find anything better on this site fast, but constrained convex optimization isn't exactly hard to find if you search.

Comment: @Macavity you can not use here the convex optimization because there is a condition. I still think that your solution is total wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg At the risk of repeating everything, the condition is what defines the domain. Within the domain, which has to be closed and continuous (which it is here), convexity works. Simply put, no interior point of the domain can be the maximant due to the function being concave. Hence the result. I will see if a clearer eg is available somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume $z=\min\{x,y,z\}$ then note $\sqrt{1-xy}+\sqrt{1-yz}+\sqrt{1-xz}\geq\sqrt{1-\frac{(2-z)^2}{4}}+2\sqrt[4]{(1-yz)(1-xz)}=\sqrt{z-\frac{z^2}{4}}+2\sqrt[4]{1-z(2-z)+z^2xy}\geq\sqrt{z-\frac{z^2}{4}}+2\sqrt[4]{(1-z)^2+z^4}\geq 2$

Comment: Nice +1.  You should also show how the last expression is min when $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks. As the last expression is a single variable case, I left it for the proposer of the problem.

Comment: The last inequality is not easy, but it's true.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes you are right. Now it seems without computer its very hard. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume that $x \ge y \ge z$.

We have
$$\sqrt{1 - xy} \ge \sqrt{1 - (x + y)^2/4}.$$
Also, we have
$$\sqrt{1 - yz} + \sqrt{1 - zx} \ge 1 + \sqrt{1 - yz - zx}.$$
(*Note*: Squaring both sides, it is just
$2\sqrt{1 - yz - zx + z^2xy} \ge 2\sqrt{1 - yz - zx}$.)

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{1 - (x + y)^2/4} + 1 + \sqrt{1 - yz - zx} \ge 2$$
or
$$\sqrt{1 - (2 - z)^2/4} + \sqrt{1 - (2 - z)z} \ge 1$$
or
$$\frac12\sqrt{z(4 - z)} + (1 - z) \ge 1$$
which is true (using $z \le 2/3$).

We are done.

Comment: -how did you come up with that solution, what were your thought process?

Comment: @PhilosophicalNature First, we know $\sqrt{1 - u} + \sqrt{1 - v} \ge \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1 - u - v}$ for $u, v \ge 0$ with $u + v \le 1$ (actually, one may use Karamata inequality for concave function $\sqrt u$). Second, the expression is minimized at $x = y = 1, z = 0$. It happens $\sqrt{1 - yz} + \sqrt{1 - zx} = \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1 - yz - zx}$ at it. So I tried this estimate.